# How can we run a function when I clicked on Radio button in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have three radio buttons and when I click on one radio button I want to have some functionality using jQuery.

Comment: Do you know which button you want the function to fire on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would fire the code when you click on (for example) the second radio. Is that what you meant?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/z2f5j/

HTML

```
<input type='radio' name='somename' />one
<input type='radio' name='somename' />two
<input type='radio' name='somename' />​three​​​
```

jQuery

```
    // :eq() uses a 0 based index, so 1 is the 2nd radio
$(':radio[name=somename]:eq(1)').click(function() {
    alert('i was clicked');
});​
```

You could also use a `change` event, instead of `click`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/z2f5j/2/

```
      // run code when the radio is selected
$(':radio[name=somename]:eq(1)').change(function() {
    alert('i was changed');
});​
```

- http://api.jquery.com/eq/
- http://api.jquery.com/click/
- http://api.jquery.com/change/